# Shouldn't Helen of Troy be Helen of Sparta?

Tags: greek, trojan-war

Wasn't the Trojan war fought precisely because Helen was *not* of Troy, but of Sparta? How come we call her "Helen of Troy."

Comment: They would probably have said "Helen of Sparta" if they were going that direction.  They were independent kingdoms.

Answer (score 3):

She is actually also known as beautiful Helen, Helen of Argos, or Helen of Sparta, depending on the source - and not all sources associate Helen with Troy.

Euripides, Stesichorus, and Herodotus actually write Helen never went to Troy, but stayed in Egypt during the duration of the Trojan War.

The Trojan association is the most popular nowadays, primarily because of the general awareness of (the existence of) Homer's work...and Hollywood.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because of the argument: which came first?
The Trojan War, Menelaus, and Helen were circa c 1194–1184 BC (Modern dating: c. 1260–1180 BC); whilst Sparta came into being circa 800 BC.  Ergo: there wasn’t a Sparta at the time.

Comment: Mind you Menelaus and Helen are not considered historically attested.

Comment: What about Helen of Laconia?